# How to set up multiple windows?

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, window, portal

I need 2 Windows - One Admin & One public - In real time the public window needs to update from actions taken in admin.

I am making a simple app that from actions taken in admin(back end) will show in the public viewable window(front end) so this needs to be in real time. I do not want a refresh on the front end either. Can someone point me in the right direction as in jquery/ajax or whatever - An example would be live chat in functionality.

To simplify - I click a button on the back end and the result will show on the front end as the viewer looks at that page.

Answer (score 0):

The Request Architect in Http is half-duplex means, The client send a request to a **Know Server** (Known IP Address) and Server Replies.

There is No Way in Http Protocol For a Server to Request Access a client since **Client** IP Address can be change (it may use a proxy or connection could be behind a NAT Server) and The Http losses TCP Connection After each Client Request.

So in this Situation for a *Chat* Application There Are Two Approach Solutions to make Client Inform That Server Data Has been Changed (Push Messages).

The First : **Polling**

check for changes every time Intervals.

Its Simple to implement but not very efficient.

it can be very resource heavy in server or client.

The Second : **Listening** *Recommended*

is Another Way That Client Register to a Listening Channel.

after each Data Change. Client Would Understand The Change.

There Are Technical Steps and Issues like:

Registering to Channel, disconnecting, ....

Solution:

you can make this happen with **Web Socket** Protocol or using dedicate services like Google Firebase.

it cannot achievable using Http and Ajax.

Tutorials You can find:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/websockets/websockets_api.htm